# How can I create a new repo with a subset of files from another repo?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I have a large repository with many modules and functionality.

Lately I have been working on one module on my own branch `add_function_to_module`

However it is time that I have this module on a separate repository.

(Just in case I *do not want to erase the module* from the original repo)

How can I do this?

I know the most obvious option is to just git init a repo, copy the necessary files and start git commiting.

But are there other (better) options?

Perhaps some that preserve the commits I have been working on?

(Also I am not the administrator of the original repo, but I will be on the new repo)